# How to sort vector of struct C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

I'm trying to sort vector of `struct`, but it ends with error. I tried to do it according to C++ reference, but I don't know where the problem is. Could someone help me?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
struct reg{
    string name;
    string addr;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

 vector <reg> a;
    reg newReg = { "John", "Street1"};
    a.push_back(newReg);
    reg newReg2 = { "Mike", "Street2"};
    a.push_back(newReg2);
    std::sort (a.begin(), a.end());  

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on said error?

Answer (score 4):

Unlike build-in types like `int`, `float` etc, you have to define the compare function for `struct reg`, i.e. rules that you want the elements to follow when sorting. Like this:

```
bool my_compare(const struct reg &x, const struct reg &y)
{
    // define how to compare x,y here
}
```

And then, you can pass this function to sort the vector:

```
std::sort (a.begin(), a.end(), my_compare);
```

Comment: The method `my_compare` should probably return an int. A predicate function is only useful for partitioning not sorting.

Comment: @NickC: Um, no?  The third parameter to `std::sort` is a predicate function...  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort "comparison function object [...] which returns `​true` if the first argument is [before] the second element. The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following: `bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`"

Comment: @MooingDuck I stand corrected. I blame my new job working with C# which returns an int. The rust grows faster than I thought.

Comment: @NickC Yeah, C# does need a `int`. :P

Answer (score 0):

You either have to overload the comparison operator (less than, afair) or provide a custom comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell std::sort what makes one instance of the struct "less than" another instance of the struct.

In other words, if I give you two instances of those structs filled with data, and ask you "which one is placed before the other?", what is your answer?  The rules you used to come with that answer is what you need to code and give to the 3 argument version of std::sort.